# Table dropdown menu disappears in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When you click on the drop-down menu next to "size" or "gender" in Firefox, the menu appears for a split second and then disappears. This happens on all of the individual product pages for this site. It seems to be working fine in other browsers.

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is occurring.

Any ideas??

Here's the link:

http://chathamivy.com/shop/the-coastal-collection/catch-of-the-day/

This is the PHP for the form:

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
<?php if ( ! empty( $available_variations ) ) : ?>
    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php $loop = 0; foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
                    <td class="value"><select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">
                        <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>
                        <?php
                            if ( is_array( $options ) ) {

                                if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                    $selected_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                    $selected_value = $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                } else {
                                    $selected_value = '';
                                }

                                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                                if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {

                                    $orderby = wc_attribute_orderby( $name );

                                    switch ( $orderby ) {
                                        case 'name' :
                                            $args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => false, 'menu_order' => false );
                                        break;
                                        case 'id' :
                                            $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'menu_order' => false, 'hide_empty' => false );
                                        break;
                                        case 'menu_order' :
                                            $args = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false );
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    $terms = get_terms( $name, $args );

                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) )
                                            continue;

                                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                                    }
                                } else {

                                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select> <?php
                        if ( sizeof( $attributes ) == $loop )
                            echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
                    ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <div class="single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' ); ?>

        <div class="single_variation"></div>

        <div class="variations_button">
            <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" />

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The select looks like it's being rebuilt whenever it has focus. There's probably some javascript somewhere messing it up, I'm not going to dig through the entire site for you, but a starting point would be to look for events in your javascript related to Select elements.

Comment: Thanks MLeFevre. I don't know enough javascript to understand where I would find this and/or how to fix it. Is there any hack you could suggest that might patch the problem?

Answer (score 0):

do you use any other language to generate these dropdown menus?

As it written on your page it works fine for me.

[Check this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/9ks9W/1/)

```
<select id="size" name="attribute_size">
    <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
    <option class="active" value="extra-small">Extra Small</option>
    <option class="active" value="small">Small</option>
    <option class="active" value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option class="active" value="large">Large</option>
    <option class="active" value="extra-large">Extra Large</option>
</select>
<select id="gender" name="attribute_gender">
    <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
    <option class="active" value="womens">Womens</option>
    <option class="active" value="youth">Youth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Callie. The site is built on the Woocommerce framework. I just pasted the PHP code above in my question.